# Request limit violation update cannot show on client

Tags: docusignapi

I can see the below point in docusign documentation https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/rules-and-limits/

`2. Apps are limited to one GET status request per unique envelope per 15 minutes. If you exceed this limit, the request will not fail, but it will be flagged as a violation of rate limits, which can cause your app to fail review to go-live. To avoid exceeding this limit, design your app to poll at 20-minute intervals rather than 15 or, rather than polling for envelope status, your integration can subscribe to Connect to get status updates for the envelope.`

My requirement is to poll the documents for each user using API:

`GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/<account_id>/envelopes?count=10&from_date=2021-10-21T04:38:51.0930000Z&include=recipients&order_by=last_modified&order=asc&folder_types=normal,inbox,sentitems,draft&start_position=0`

and there documents using API:

`GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/<account_id>/envelopes/<envelope_id>/documents`

and I have multiple user connection with same account Id, hitting these two APIs.
will it be flagged as rate limit violation? I have tried these GET api again and again but I can't see this violation status on my client? how can get update of this if in case it happens on my prod instance?

Answer (score 1):

### What is the goal of this API call?

```
GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/<account_id>/envelopes?count=10&
from_date=2021-10-21T04:38:51.0930000Z&include=recipients&
order_by=last_modified&order=asc&
folder_types=normal,inbox,sentitems,draft&start_position=0
```

Is it to monitor incoming envelopes? If so you can use [Recipient Connect](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/recipient-connect) to receive webhook notifications.

Otherwise, for a given DocuSign user, you can make the API call once every 15 minutes or less often.

You cannot make the call more often than once per 15 minutes per associated user. If your app uses a "system user" such as finance@your-company.com then you cannot call it more than once per 15 minutes since the results would not change.

### And what is the goal of this API call?

```
GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/<account_id>/
envelopes/<envelope_id>/documents
```

The documents in an envelope are generally not going to change.
More often, apps want to know when an envelope has completed, and then download the docs.

### Update

The polling limits are:

- per user
- results must be expected to change

This means that you cannot poll after an envelope reaches a terminal state. IE only poll if the envelope is in the `sent` or `delivered` states.

And it is still not clear to me why an envelope's documents will change.

If you want to provide the current version of the envelope's documents to your application's user, give them a button to download the documents. Don't poll for them.

Finally remember the limit of 1,000 API calls per hour per account for your application. Your application will NOT be approved for additional API calls per hour with this type of polling activity.

Comment: ```GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/<account_id>/envelopes?count=10&
from_date=2021-10-21T04:38:51.0930000Z&include=recipients&
order_by=last_modified&order=asc&
folder_types=normal,inbox,sentitems,draft&start_position=0```

This API is for monitoring polling envelopes only and my requirement is of polling thats why I am not considering the webhooks. I can handle for the single user to hit the request after 15 minutes. But I can have multiple user belonging to one account for which I am polling the data. So will that create a problem?

Comment: Actually I am trying to poll data for each user of the account they belong and show them there envelopes and their document. So in this case I can have a single docusign client to which multiple users are connected.
And also they can belong to same account as well.

Comment: So I just want to know this API limitations is on the per user basis or the accountId basis?